# expression language: quick way to get maximum of a collection

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

Is there some tag or function that allows to get the maximum value of a collection?

I konw I can do a for loop for that, but a one liner would be better.

Comment: you could make your collection implement SortedSet and take its first element on JSP

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that with jstl or el.

The easiest is using `forEach` jstl tag.

The simple reason why there are no tags for finding the maximum value of a collection is because your collection could be anything. How would the jvm find the maximum value for a collections of "Student" objects.

Comment: Well using comparison operators... anyway it seems indeed there is no quick way of doing what I need