# Find the maximum value in jsp file

Tags: jsp

Supposing that I want to show the maximum value of an items to user.
Currently, I am using the below code:

```
<span class="orange"> <c:forEach
                items="${ProductData.terms}" var="term" varStatus="loop">${term.rate}%</c:forEach>

        </span>
```

However, with this code, It will show all values.`0.1%0.1%0.75%0.8%1.0%1.0%1.0%1.0%4.0%5.0%6.3%6.3%8.0%11.0%`

It is contrast with our expectation. I only want to show the value 11.0% here. I don't want to implement in java code...and only want to process in jsp file.
Please tell me know the way to find the maximum value in jsp file.
Thanks.

Comment: I can see some suggestions here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479115/expression-language-quick-way-to-get-maximum-of-a-collection

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate your maximum percenatge on the jsp itself,try this code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Tag Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:forEach items="${ProductData.terms}" var="percentage1">
        <fmt:parseNumber var="i" type="number" value="${percentage1}" />
        <c:forEach items="${ProductData.terms}" var="percentage2">
            <fmt:parseNumber var="j" type="number" value="${percentage2}" />
            <c:if test="${i>j}">
                <c:set var="max" value="${i}" />
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:out value="${max}" />
</body>
</html>
```

The `<fmt:parseNumber>` tag is used to parse numbers, percentages, and currencies.For more on this tag refer documentation :[JSTL fmt documenation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html)